# Player moves in a jerky way when riding on a moving platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a moving platform script that travels between three positions. This works fine.

I have a script that holds the player to a platform, and this works fine too.

But when I parent my platform that holds my player to an object with the moving platform script, the player's movement is jerky and uneven.

Here are the scripts I'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingMultipalPoint : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector3 pointB;
    public Vector3 pointC;
    public float Second = 5.0f;
    public float Speed = 3.0f;
    //public float HoldSecond = 5.0f;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Vector3 pointA = transform.position;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Second);
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointA, pointB, Speed));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Second);
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointC, Speed));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Second);
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointC, pointB, Speed));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Second);
            yield return StartCoroutine(MoveObject(transform, pointB, pointA, Speed));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform thisTransform, Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float time)
    {
        float i = 0.0f;
        float rate = 1.0f / time;
        while (i < 1.0f)
        {
            i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
            //newRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
            //transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
            thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This script holds the player to the platform.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HoldPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject target = null;
    private Vector3 offset;
    void Start()
    {
        target = null;
    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        target = col.gameObject;
        offset = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        target = null;
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.transform.position = transform.position + offset;
        }
    }
}
```

[Screeshot of Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67ysZ.jpg)

(1st Image) Here is how the moving platform is configured in the Inspector:

(2nd Image) And the holding script:

[Also here recorded video of issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKr8zZZfUSA)

Any ideas how I can keep the movement smooth in this case?

Comment: what if move the code inside `HoldPlayer`'s `LateUpdate` into the `MoveObject` coroutine? however it might need a little tweak but it should fix the jerky movement

Comment: you mean IEnumerator MoveObject()?

Comment: then void LateUpdate(){start coroutine (MoveObject())}?

Comment: ya i tried but same issue

Comment: Your problem is here `thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, i);` You're translating the position of the objects instead of using some physics.